# Connection between chrome extension and Azure text analytics API

Tags: javascript, azure, api, google-chrome-extension

I am trying establish connection between my chrome extension and text analytics API. I have created background.js to deal with connection after extension is installed to chrome but it's throwing error code: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

How can I establish connection between extension and Azure TA API?

Comment: Since `404` is a `Not Found`: is the endpoint URL complete and correct?

Comment: endpoint URL is correct

Comment: Are you using the correct `METHOD`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a JavaScript library you can use: [Azure Text Analytics client library for JavaScript](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/textanalytics/ai-text-analytics). The GitHub repo has a lot of examples, like this one for detecting the language:

```
const documents = [
  "This document is written in English.",
  "Este es un document escrito en Español.",
  "这是一个用中文写的文件",
  "Dies ist ein Dokument in deutsche Sprache.",
  "Detta är ett dokument skrivet på engelska."
];

const client = new TextAnalyticsClient(endpoint, new AzureKeyCredential(apiKey));
const results = await client.detectLanguage(documents);
```